# Extract specific columns from line and match against given range

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to identify numbers(float) within a certain range from text using regex, the text format is:

`3  1  EDR  918771665157  ^[[32m97.01424  ^[[0m918489349209  ^[[32m97.01408   ^[[0m
3  2  EDR  918493379596  ^[[32m87.01418  ^[[0m918775654999  ^[[32m87.01434   ^[[0m`

The `^[[32m` and `^[[0m` strings are because of colors.
I'm trying to check if the 5th and 7th columns are between 93.00000 and 99.99999,
however if the value is 93.00000 it might be shown as 93.
I tried the following:`9[3-9](\.\d{1,5})?\s+\S+\s+.*9[3-9](\.\d{1,5})?` but i have a problem since in the second line here the 5th and 7th columns are not in range but i get true because of the 4th and 6th columns

Comment: a dirty trick `m9[3-9]..........`

Comment: you might need to match complete line

Comment: Why aren't you matching something like `^(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\^\[\[\d+.)?9[3-9]` etc. It's not that difficult to determine which column you're working with if you have an easy to work with space delimiter.

Comment: Do you have to use a single regex or can you split the string into an array and work on that? Should be way easier.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to split the line so that you can get the exact columns and then do desired processing on those columns. See the below approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while(<DATA>){
    chomp;
    my @columns = split/\s+/, $_;
    my $fifth_column = $columns[4];
    my $seventh_column = $columns[6];

    #Remove ^[[32m and ^[[0m
    $fifth_column =~ s/\^\[\[32m|\^\[\[0m//g;
    $seventh_column =~ s/\^\[\[32m|\^\[\[0m//g;

    #Verify that above are between 93.00000 and 99.99999
}

__DATA__
3  1  EDR  918771665157  ^[[32m97.01424  ^[[0m918489349209  ^[[32m97.01408   ^[[0m
3  2  EDR  918493379596  ^[[32m87.01418  ^[[0m918775654999  ^[[32m87.01434   ^[[0m
```